# RewriteRule when the substitution string is not a file path but an URL which should be processed by next rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I would like every request

```
example.com/foo/anything
```

to be rewritten into `example.com/foo-anything` before being processed by Wordpress.

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)   foo-$1       # <-- does not work because the subs. string should be a *file path*

# The following is set by Wordpress
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

but it does not work because the substitution (destination) string is supposed to be a file path, not another URL.

**How to make such a RewriteRule for which the substitution string is not a file path, but an URL, that should be processed by next rules?**

Notes:

- With `RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)   foo-$1    [R]`, it works but then it causes a browser redirection and *the URL changes in the URL bar of the browser*, which I don't want.
- I tried with [RewriteRule flag `[PT]`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt) which should work even when the substitution string is not a file path, but it did not work for me: it does not redirect `/foo/anything` to page `/foo-anything`.
- I tried

  ```
     RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)   index.php?name=foo-$1  [L]
  ```

  but then it only works for articles, but not *pages*. I would like a solution working for both pages and articles.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a WordPress problem, at least partially. It parses the originally requested URL, and doesn't take any _internal_ rewrites into account. (If it did, then the whole thing would not work to begin with, because then it would always just see `/index.php`, and would have no idea what content it is supposed to show based on that.)

Comment: I think you might have more luck, if you set this up using https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/

Comment: WP framework won't work with internal rewrite rules in .htaccess. You will have to use WP rewrite API inside your theme php file.

Comment: @CBroe I've used this WP function `add_rewrite_rule` before, but I noticed what it finally does is that it rewrites the `.htaccess` file :) Also this function `add_rewrite_rule` seems to have the same limitation: the substitution string has to be a file path (such as `anything.php?query=foo`) and not another URL. The question is: how does WP have access to the *originally requested URL*?

Comment: @anubhava I've tried it before, but the same problem occured, see my other comment. But, by the way, how does WP access to the originally requested URL?

Comment: "how does WP have access to the originally requested URL?" - Presumably through the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. "I tried with RewriteRule flag `[PT]` which should work" - That only applies when used in a _server_ context. In `.htaccess` `PT` is essentially the default behaviour. Incidentally, in `.htaccess`, the subs-string is seen as a URL-path, not a file-path (particularly since `RewriteBase` is defined)..

Comment: @MrWhite I think you can post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, this does not seem possible.

Either it's a RewriteRule with [R] redirection flag, and then the browser will do a new request, then in this case the target/substitution can be any new URL...

... or it's *not* a redirection RewriteRule and then the target/substitution has to be a file that serves the request.

See also [How to use RewriteRule such that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is modified too for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69673965/how-to-use-rewriterule-such-that-serverrequest-uri-is-modified-too-for-php)

---

In a Wordpress context, a (working) hack is to *not* use a .htaccess RewriteRule but do this instead in `functions.php`:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace(..., ..., $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```