# How to use RewriteRule such that $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is modified too for PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, request-uri

With this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule foo/(.*) /foo-$1         # here I tried [L], [PT], [C], etc.
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I've tried all possible flags for the first RewriteRule, but always, this PHP code:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

always echoes `/foo/bar` instead of `/foo-bar`, when accessing http://example.com/foo/bar. Why?

**How to have Apache's RewriteEngine also modify the `REQUEST_URI` that will be seen by PHP?**

Note: I don't want [R] because a redirection would generate a new browser request, and change the URL displayed in the URL bar, which I don't want.

See also [RewriteRule when the substitution string is not a file path but an URL which should be processed by next rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662962/rewriterule-when-the-substitution-string-is-not-a-file-path-but-an-url-which-sho).

Comment: I am not sure there is a way to do that, from the Apache end only. This here is a similar topic, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618316/1427878 - but the solution suggested there is to look for the value in `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` afterwards, which probably won't help you much here, because I am assuming you are still asking this in the context of your previous, WordPress related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69662962/1427878

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` is useful after rewriting as it gives you access to the original, unwritten url... both in PHP and inside mod_rewrite rules e.g. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ # user originally requested a php file`. Not changing it would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, it seems that PHP will always see the original URL in  `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and not the target of the RewriteRule. (authoritative source needed here).

By the way, the target of a RewriteRule is usually *a file* that will process the request, except if we use a [R] redirection flag, then in this case the browser will do a new request to the new URL (and the browser URL bar changes).

Answer (score 3):

I think what you try to do is impossible without some work around.
I have provided 2 solutions in this post, one using auto_prepend_file and one using mod_proxy.

### Solution 1: using auto_prepend_file

Please look at the script below, this does not directly set the REQUEST_URI global, but instead it overwrites it in PHP, with the following code:

### .htaccess

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "before.php" 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule foo/(.*) /foo-$1
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Make sure to add this line:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "before.php"
```

### before.php

In this script you can replace the REQUEST_URI:

Like:

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/" . str_replace('/', '-', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/"));
```

You can further improve this script, but I think the concept is clear.

### index.php

Index.php is unaffected but contains the rewritten rule:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //string(7) "/foo-bar"
```

A request to `http://localhost/foo/bar?test` is now: `string(13) "/foo-bar?test"`

### Update

When using [L], you can obtain the rewritten url by:

```php
var_dump($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']); # /foo-bar
```

So the .htaccess becomes:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "before.php" 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule foo/(.*) /foo-$1 [L] # please note [L] here
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Thus the before.php can be replaced by:

```php
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
```

### Update solution 2; using mod_proxy

Found out you can also use mod proxy:

I had to enable the following modules:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
```

Now your .htaccess is changed to (notice the [P] flag):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/(.+)$ /foo-$1 [L,P]
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This will proxy all foo/bar requests to /foo-bar and change the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` accordingly.

```php
var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); //output: string(8) "/foo-bar"
```

I think using the PHP prepend file is a more efficient way though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the Apache `original-uri` and not `current-uri`.

> [CGIVar Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#cgivar)

With this `.htaccess` file:

```
CGIVar REQUEST_URI current-uri
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

then a request to `example.com/hello/world` will give:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  "/index.php"
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"] "/hello/world"
```

Without the `CGIVar` line, it would give "/hello/world" for both `REQUEST_URI` and `REDIRECT_URL`.